# testng from ant: specify -server -Xms?

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, testng

I'm running testng from ant using the  task.  I'd really like to add the -server option to the forked jvm as well as specifying the amount of heap space.  Anyone know how to do it?

I don't see anything here:
http://testng.org/doc/ant.html

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you posted specifies that you can pass JVM arguments with a `<jvmarg value="blah"/>` element. Have you tried this?

```
<testng>
    <jvmarg value="-server"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
    ...
```

Comment: chalk another question up for me as, "I am an idiot".  Thanks for spelling this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [ant via java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava). This way you can specify -server and -Xms.

Comment: ant's jvm isn't the problem.  You can specify those things in the ANT_OPTS env variable.  The issue is that the testng task forks another jvm.  It's that jvm that I would like to add these options to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<testing>
    <jvmarg line="-server -Xmx128m"/>
```

Than you can specify any number of JVM arguments in a single line.